# Apache Camel: Nested filters (filter ... filter ... end ...filter ... end ..end) in DSL (Groovy or Java)

Tags: filter, nested, apache-camel, dsl

we have some issues with the DSL for Camel Routes. It seems that it is not possible to translate the following XML Configuration into the Groovy (or JAVA) DSL

```
    <route id="myroute" >
        <from uri="fromURI" />
        <filter>
            <xpath>//entity[contains(@destinations, 'databasedestination')]</xpath>
            <filter>
                <xpath>//entity[@objectType = 'objectType']</xpath>
                <camel:setHeader headerName="bodyTemp">
                    <simple>${body}</simple>
                </camel:setHeader>
                <filter>
                    <xpath>//entity[@command = 'add']</xpath>
                    <convertBodyTo type="com.foo.bar.Entity" />
                    <bean ref="handler" method="add" />
                </filter>
                <filter>
                    <xpath>//entity[@command = 'foo']</xpath>
                    <convertBodyTo type="com.foo.bar.Entity" />
                    <bean ref="handler" method="foo" />
                </filter>
                <filter>
                    <xpath>//entity[@command = 'bar']</xpath>
                    <convertBodyTo type="com.foo.bar.Entity" />
                    <bean ref="handler" method="bar" />
                </filter>
                <to uri="toURI" />      
            </filter>
        </filter>
    </route>
```

Wie tried to translate it inside a Groovy based RouteBuilder as follows:

```
from("fromURI")
        .filter().xpath('//entity[contains(@destinations, \'databasedestination\')]')
            .setHeader("bodyTemp", simple('${body}'))
            .filter().xpath('//entity[@objectType = \'objectType\']')

                .filter().xpath('//entity[@command = \'add\']')
                    .convertBodyTo(com.foo.bar.Entity)
                    .bean(handler, "add")   
                .end()
                .filter().xpath('//entity[@command = \'foo\']')
                    .convertBodyTo(com.foo.bar.Entity)
                    .bean(handler, "foo")
                .end()
                .filter().xpath('//entity[@command = \'bar\']')
                    .convertBodyTo(com.foo.bar.Entity)
                    .bean(handler, "bar")
                .end()

                .to("toURI")
            .end()
        .end()
```

But that obviously doesn't work. We get a `javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException` with the Message: `Invalid xpath: //entity[@command = 'foo']`

See the corresponding stacktrace as well.

```
    ->>  814 | doInEvaluateAs      in org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XPathBuilder
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    |    697 | evaluateAs          in     ''
    |    139 | matches . . . . . . in     ''
    |     47 | process             in org.apache.camel.processor.FilterProcessor
    |     73 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper
    |     99 | processNext         in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |     90 | process . . . . . . in     ''
    |     73 | process             in org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor
    |     99 | processNext . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |     90 | process             in     ''
    |     91 | process . . . . . . in             org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor
    |     73 | process             in org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper
    |    330 | processErrorHandler in org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler
    |    220 | process             in     ''
    |     45 | processNext . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor
    |     90 | process             in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |    303 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel
    |     73 | process             in org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper
    |    117 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline
    |     80 | process             in     ''
    |     45 | processNext . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor
    |     90 | process             in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |    150 | processAsync . . .  in org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor
    |    117 | process             in     ''
    |     48 | processNext . . . . in     org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor
    |     90 | process             in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |     73 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper
    |     99 | processNext         in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |     90 | process . . . . . . in     ''
    |     73 | process             in org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor
    |     99 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper
    |     86 | process             in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |    105 | onMessage . . . . . in    org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener
    |   1110 | runWorker           in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
    |    603 | run . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
    ^    722 | run                 in java.lang.Thread
    Caused by XPathExpressionException: null
    ->>  200 | evaluate            in     com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    |    800 | doInEvaluateAs      in org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XPathBuilder
    |    697 | evaluateAs . . . .  in     ''
    |    139 | matches             in     ''
    |     47 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.FilterProcessor
    |     73 | process             in org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper
    |     99 | processNext . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |     90 | process             in     ''
    |     73 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor
    |     99 | processNext         in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |     90 | process . . . . . . in     ''
    |     91 | process             in    org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor
    |     73 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper
    |    330 | processErrorHandler in org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler
    |    220 | process . . . . . . in     ''
    |     45 | processNext         in org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor
    |     90 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |    303 | process             in org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel
    |     73 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper
    |    117 | process             in org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline
    |     80 | process . . . . . . in     ''
    |     45 | processNext         in org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor
    |     90 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |    150 | processAsync        in org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor
    |    117 | process . . . . . . in     ''
    |     48 | processNext         in      org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor
    |     90 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |     73 | process             in org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper
    |     99 | processNext . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |     90 | process             in     ''
    |     73 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor
    |     99 | process             in org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper
    |     86 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |    105 | onMessage           in     org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener
    |   1110 | runWorker . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
    |    603 | run                 in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
    ^    722 | run . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
    Caused by TransformerException: Unable to evaluate expression using this context
    ->>  367 | execute             in com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath
     - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    |    129 | eval                in     com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl
    |    105 | eval . . . . . . .  in     ''
    |    187 | evaluate            in     ''
    |    800 | doInEvaluateAs . .  in org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XPathBuilder
    |    697 | evaluateAs          in     ''
    |    139 | matches . . . . . . in     ''
    |     47 | process             in org.apache.camel.processor.FilterProcessor
    |     73 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper
    |     99 | processNext         in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |     90 | process . . . . . . in     ''
    |     73 | process             in org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor
    |     99 | processNext . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |     90 | process             in     ''
    |     91 | process . . . . . . in     org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor
    |     73 | process             in org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper
    |    330 | processErrorHandler in org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler
    |    220 | process             in     ''
    |     45 | processNext . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor
    |     90 | process             in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |    303 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel
    |     73 | process             in org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper
    |    117 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline
    |     80 | process             in     ''
    |     45 | processNext . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor
    |     90 | process             in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |    150 | processAsync . . .  in org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor
    |    117 | process             in     ''
    |     48 | processNext . . . . in     org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor
    |     90 | process             in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |     73 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper
    |     99 | processNext         in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |     90 | process . . . . . . in     ''
    |     73 | process             in org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor
    |     99 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper
    |     86 | process             in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |    105 | onMessage . . . . . in     org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener
    |   1110 | runWorker           in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
    |    603 | run . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
    ^    722 | run                 in java.lang.Thread
    Caused by RuntimeException: Unable to evaluate expression using this context
    ->>  266 | setRoot             in com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.NodeSequence
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    |    214 | execute             in     com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.LocPathIterator
    |    339 | execute . . . . . . in com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath
    |    129 | eval                in     com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl
    |    105 | eval . . . . . . .  in     ''
    |    187 | evaluate            in     ''
    |    800 | doInEvaluateAs . .  in org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XPathBuilder
    |    697 | evaluateAs          in     ''
    |    139 | matches . . . . . . in     ''
    |     47 | process             in org.apache.camel.processor.FilterProcessor
    |     73 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper
    |     99 | processNext         in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |     90 | process . . . . . . in     ''
    |     73 | process             in org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor
    |     99 | processNext . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |     90 | process             in     ''
    |     91 | process . . . . . . in     org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor
    |     73 | process             in org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper
    |    330 | processErrorHandler in org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler
    |    220 | process             in     ''
    |     45 | processNext . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor
    |     90 | process             in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |    303 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel
    |     73 | process             in org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper
    |    117 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline
    |     80 | process             in     ''
    |     45 | processNext . . . . in org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor
    |     90 | process             in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |    150 | processAsync . . .  in org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor
    |    117 | process             in     ''
    |     48 | processNext . . . . in     org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor
    |     90 | process             in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |     73 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper
    |     99 | processNext         in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |     90 | process . . . . . . in     ''
    |     73 | process             in org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor
    |     99 | process . . . . . . in org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper
    |     86 | process             in org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor
    |    105 | onMessage . . . . . in     org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener
    |   1110 | runWorker           in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
    |    603 | run . . . . . . . . in     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
    ^    722 | run                 in java.lang.Thread
```

Thank you for any help

Markus

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be more fitting for a Content Based Router, making use of the choice EIP.

Are you able to make use of a choice statement instead? http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html

Comment: I don't think that this will work for the shown scenario. I'd rather like to solve it via filters and I think I need too. Please explain me what is actually wrong with my example?